# Configuration for wsl2 for first time

Tags: windows, ubuntu-gnome

I'm a windows 10 user ..and I like to use Ubuntu in windows..so I choose wsl 2 and I don't know nothing about wsl 1 & 2 ..can anyone please help me on this wsl2 and configuration . And also how to run Linux GUI apps on windows using WSL2

Comment: WSL is not for running graphical apps.

Answer (score 1):

ADD

```
export DISPLAY=`cat /etc/resolv.conf|grep nameserver|awk '{print $2}'`:0
```

to your `~/.bash_profile`

Then install a Xwindow Server on your windows host and allow the server to listen remotely. You will be able to run a GUI app after that.